# Browser does not decompress gzip assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, gzip, mod-deflate

I've enabled `gzip` for by Ruby on Rails application using [webpack](https://github.com/rails/webpacker)

After `asset:precompile`, I can see gzipped assets in my public folder.

This is my configuration for Apache, where I'm asking it to serve gzip assets when available -

```
 <LocationMatch "^/assets/.*$">
    Header unset ETag
    FileETag None
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    Header merge Cache-Control public
    Header unset Set-Cookie
    SetEnv no-gzip
  </LocationMatch>

  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} \b(x-)?gzip\b
  RewriteCond /path/to/app/public%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -s
  RewriteRule ^(.+) $1.gz [L]

  <FilesMatch \.css\.gz$>
    ForceType text/css
    Header set Content-Encoding gzip
  </FilesMatch>
```

But then, when I'm loading the app from the browser, it seems as though the browser is trying to evaluate the gzipped javascript file as is without performing decompression.

[image: Preview of a gzipped JS file from the browser console]

[image: Response Headers]

Am I doing something wrong with the configuration in Apache?